# how to convert a list of floats to int in python ;err int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to convert my list of floats to ints, but I keep getting the error 
`int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'`

This is my code, and values is the list in floats.

```
values = [my_random() for x in range(num_trials)]
vals_to = [int(x*100) for x in values]
```

and I'm doing this in jupyter notebook. When I try samples they turn out fine, but I'm so confused on why this particular code of list is giving me this error.
Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: What’s `my_random`? If it returns a list of floats instead of a single float, you’ll need to nest another list comprehension to turn the list of list of floats into a list of list of ints.

Comment: the problem is with your `my_random` this is returning a list apparently

Comment: @Ry- thanks guys that was causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to make sure that your function **my_random()** returns a float number.

Anyway, let's say you have a list of float numbers

```
mylist = [3.1415, 74.2, 345.03, 98.9]
```

There are many ways to achieve your task. For example,

```
res = [int(i) for i in mylist] # 1 List comprehension
res = list(map(int, mylist)) # 2 Map
```

For more control on how to round each number, you can use **math**

```
import math

res = list(map(math.ceil, mylist)) # Round up
res = list(map(math.floor, mylist)) # Round down
```